# acro package across two types of languages

Tags: acro

I just use the acro package to typeset my thesis in Chinese, with the following example:

```
\documentclass[UTF8,a4paper,zihao=-4,fontset=fandol]{ctexart}

\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{hi}{
    short = Hi,
    long = 你好,
    foreign = Hello}

\begin{document}

\ac{hi} % will generate 你好 (Hello, Hi)

\end{document}
```

This example meets the requirements in various Chinese environments. However, when I transfer to pure English environments, I want to locally let `long` be equal to `foreign`, and ignore `foreign`. The thing that I want to do, is

```
\documentclass[UTF8,a4paper,zihao=-4,fontset=fandol]{ctexart}

\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{hi}{
    short = Hi,
    long = 你好,
    foreign = Hello}

\begin{document}

% Chinese

\ac{hi} % will generate 你好 (Hello, Hi)

\begingroup % pure English

\ac{hi} % expect to generate Hello (Hi)

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

In addition, are there some ways to use `\MakeTextLowercase` for the `foreign` in Chinese or for the `long` in English?

By the way, the example should be compiled with xelatex.

Comment: This issue has been discussed here: https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/153